# How to correctly register font-awesome for md-icon?

Tags: angular-material2

The documentation of [md-icon](https://material.angular.io/components/component/icon) describes how to use font-awesome in several parts and suggests we could use font-awesome eventually like

```
<md-icon fontSet="fa" fontIcon="alarm"></md-icon>
```

But the documentation is very confusing and I can hardly find a routine to register 3rd font set like font-awesome for md-icon via Google.

Any help is appreciated!

PS: I know the normal `<i>` way generally works but it doesn't seem working in some [examples](https://material.angular.io/components/component/list), where the md-icon is used originally.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add font awesome cdn link in your Index.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Then try putting this code, It's working for me:

```
<md-icon class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></md-icon>
<md-icon class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></md-icon>
```

Comment: This is surprisingly simple. Thanks.

Comment: This is not the correct way to register font-awesome for md-icon. Please see answer below.

Comment: I know the other way is the Angular way. This is too much easier. I had to add `.mat-icon.fa {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}` to my global stylesheet.

Comment: @SeanStanden granted this isn't the "angular way" to do this, but do you know any technical reasons why using this approach would not be appropriate? I'm interested to know as I have used the above approach before, and wonder if there's any danger/problems to using it?

Comment: @AaronLavers the answer above isn't using mat-icon. It's putting a mat-icon element on the page, then applying a font-awesome class to it. It bypasses any presentation logic that exists within the mat-icon properties. I doubt there is any difference between doing above, and simply using <i> instead.

Answer (score 88):

In your AppModule add:

```
import { MatIconModule, MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';
```

Then add MatIconModule to your imports e.g.:

```
imports: [...
   MatIconModule
...]
```

Add MatIconRegistry to your providers:

```
providers: [...
    MatIconRegistry
....]
```

Then add the following to your AppModule class:

```
export class AppModule {
    constructor(
        ...public matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry) {
        matIconRegistry.registerFontClassAlias('fontawesome', 'fa');
    }
```

Then you can use anywhere in your project like so:

```
<mat-icon fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-times-circle"></mat-icon>
```

**Update**

You'll need to include fontawesome in your project somewhere. I use angular-cli so adding the font-awesome npm package:

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

and including it in styles list in angular-cli.json file works for me:

```
"styles": [
    ...
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
  ],
```

**Update 2**

Changed prefixes to 'Mat' to reflect recent updates to angular material.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I can however use the default `<i class="fa fa-icon">` and it works correctly. But using the `<mat-icon>` isn't working for me, even after setting it up exactly how you've described.

Comment: The process described above is no different to the one described here (save for adding scss library through styles array): https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview. You may want to look over your work to ensure you have followed the process thoroughly.

Comment: You can also register default font set to avoid typing fontSet="fa" in AppModule's constructor `matIconRegistry.setDefaultFontSetClass('fa');`

Comment: Well it wasn't working with font awesome 4. But I added in the new webfont with Font Awesome 5 and this works.

Comment: The AppModule step is not necessary if you use `fontSet="fa"`. Adding it enables you to alternatively use the alias `fontSet="fontawesome"`.

Comment: @hovado matIconRegistry.setDefaultFontSetClass('fa') work well but now I am unable to use material icons.

Answer (score 0):

I've setup https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#using-the-icon-library

The way I then use it:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput style="width: calc(100% - 20px);/>
    <fa-icon [icon]="['fal', 'home']" size="lg" class="fa-pull-right"></fa-icon>                  
</mat-form-field>
```